# React Router | Component not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, code-splitting

I have a SPA with multiple routes. I am trying to implement Code Splitting based on routes using Webpack 2 and React Router 4. I am able to create different chunks based on the routes. For example, for the homepage I have a `vendor.js`, `main.js` and `home.js`. All three files are loaded successfully but I am not seeing any output. `null` is being rendered. Below is the screenshot of React developer tools and code used. May I know what am I missing here?

[image]

**App Component / App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotificationContainer from '../containers/NotificationContainer';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NotificationContainer />
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                // import('./homepage/index').then(module => callback(null, module.default));
                                require.ensure(
                                    [],
                                    require => {
                                        callback(null, require('./homepage/index').default);
                                    },
                                    'home'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/login"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['../containers/LoginContainer'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('../containers/LoginContainer');
                                    },
                                    'login'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/forgetPassword"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['../containers/ForgetPasswordContainer'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('../containers/ForgetPasswordContainer');
                                    },
                                    'forgetPassword'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/generateNewPassword"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['../containers/GenerateNewPasswordContainer'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('../containers/GenerateNewPasswordContainer');
                                    },
                                    'generateNewPassword'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/signup"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['../containers/SignupContainer'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('../containers/SignupContainer');
                                    },
                                    'signup'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/contact"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['./Contact'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('./Contact');
                                    },
                                    'contact'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/tech"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['./Tech'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('./Tech');
                                    },
                                    'tech'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/error"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['./Error'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('./Error');
                                    },
                                    'error'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/user/dashboard"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['../containers/DashBoardContainer'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('../containers/DashBoardContainer');
                                    },
                                    'dashboard'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/movie/:movieId"
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['../containers/MovieContainer'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('../containers/MovieContainer');
                                    },
                                    'movieContainer'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                                require.ensure(
                                    ['./Error'],
                                    require => {
                                        require('./Error');
                                    },
                                    'error'
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Webpack Config**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var BundleAnalyzer = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/assets/js',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'assets/js/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({ filename: './webpack-stats.json' }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: '[name].js',
            minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource)
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                keep_fnames: true
            },
            compress: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                warnings: false
            },
            comments: false
        }),
        new BundleAnalyzer({ analyzerMode: 'static' })
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    plugins: [
                        [
                            'transform-semantic-ui-react-imports',
                            {
                                convertMemberImports: true,
                                addCssImports: false,
                                importMinifiedCssFiles: false,
                                addLessImports: false,
                                addDuplicateStyleImports: false
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    presets: [['es2015', { modules: false }], 'react', 'stage-2', 'node6']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        console: true,
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    }
};
```

**Home Component | homepage/index.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import LayoutContainer from '../../containers/LayoutContainer';
import Hero from './Hero';
import About from './About';
import Working from './Working';

class Homepage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <LayoutContainer scrollBound={600}>
                <div className="homepage-container">
                    <p>Here</p>
                    <Hero />
                    <About />
                    <Working />
                </div>
            </LayoutContainer>
        );
    }
}

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the documentation for `react-router` is a big fat liar, there is no-longer a `getComponent` method for routes. Rolling your own lazy-loading component isn't too bad, though. I had to do one for a more exotic router, and this approach should work for `react-router@4` as well. First, create a simple HOC:

```
export default function DeferredComponent(loadingFn) {
  return class DeferredComponentInstance extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super(...arguments);
      this.state = {
        InnerComponent: Spinner
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      loadingFn((err, component) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;  // Maybe render an error component instead?
        }

        this.setState({ InnerComponent: component });
      });
    }

    render() {
      const { InnerComponent } = this.state;
      return <InnerComponent { ...this.props }/>;
    }
  };
}
```

...and now you can use it like this:

```
<Route
  path="/login"
  component={DeferredComponent(cb => {
    require.ensure(['../containers/LoginContainer'], require => {
      cb(null, require('../containers/LoginContainer').default);
    });
  })}
/>
```

Comment: Yes, I guess `getComponent` is really not supported now. Though web is full of it's tutorials. Any way I used this with some variations of my own to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling `callback` in all cases, so the component is not being returned to the route. For example, this:

```
<Route
  path="/login"
  getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
    require.ensure(['../containers/LoginContainer'], require => {
      require('../containers/LoginContainer');
    }, 'login');
  }}
/>
```

...should be:

```
<Route
  path="/login"
  getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
    require.ensure(['../containers/LoginContainer'], require => {
      callback(null, require('../containers/LoginContainer'));
    }, 'login');
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I am calling the callback in the `/` as in the home route still `null` is being rendered.

Comment: I'm trying to find documentation for `getComponent`, and I don't see it. Maybe that doesn't work at all anymore for `react-router`.